# In Pandas, how do I fetch a data cell in one column based on a value in another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to fetch data in one column based on data in another column with this.

```
df["column2"].where(df[df["column1"] == 'int value'])
```

However, I'm getting an error & can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
Boolean array expected for the condition, not int64
```

If I try either of these I get the right output

```
df[df["column1"] == 'int value']["column2"]
df[df["column1"] == 'int value'].column2
```

But I've been told never to use ][ and I'd rather not get into the habit of dot notation.

I'm not trying to edit the data. I just want to pull it out and see what it is.

Comment: use `df.loc[df["column1"] == 'int value','column2']` . Here is the docs : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. Could you also please explain to me the error message when I used the .where()???